# how can i add classname body scroll down react?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, gatsby

I want to when scroll down 100px , add body `className="showdiv"` on gatsby react.

How can I do this?

I try this code:

```
state = {
  isTop: true,
};

componentDidMount() {
  document.addEventListener('scroll', () => {
    const isTop = window.scrollY < 100;
    if (isTop !== this.state.isTop) {
        this.setState({ isTop })
    }
  });
}
```

classname

```
{this.state.isTop ? 'down' : 'up'}
```

But I can't add body class. I want to new and simple idea..

Thanks

Comment: Have you tried `window.addEventListener('scroll'` instead?

Comment: i dont know im new , just i want to when i scroll down 100px , add body classname just this. @Tholle

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/a/17457651/5079258

Comment: @AlanFriedman thanks for answer , how can i use this code in react ? javascript is ok but i cant work on react. u can answer reactjs code my question ?

Comment: Sure you can use it in React. Since `body` is outside of your React root, you'll need to use imperative JS to set the class.

Comment: @Tholle just i tried this code but i dont want this use. i want to just when user scroll down 100px, add body class "showChildDiv" just this.

Comment: @Tholle 'body' is outside React root i cant change className, i need a simple code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can add a scroll listener like you've done, but instead add/remove the `showChildDiv` class from the body depending on the scroll position.

**Example**

```
class App extends React.Component {
  componentDidMount() {
    window.addEventListener("scroll", this.toggleBodyClass);
    this.toggleBodyClass();
  }

  componentWillUnmount() {
    window.removeEventListener("scroll", this.toggleBodyClass);
  }

  toggleBodyClass = () => {
    if (window.scrollY < 100) {
      document.body.classList.add("showChildDiv");
    } else {
      document.body.classList.remove("showChildDiv");
    }
  };

  render() {
    return (
      <div
        style={{
          height: "1000px"
        }}
      />
    );
  }
}
```