# give body tag a custom padding for single web page only

Tags: css, html, reactjs, dom, css-selectors

I am using laravel 5.6 and react.js for my website. I have a layout file with with

```
<body>
    <div id="app">
    </div>

    <script src="{{ mix('js/app.js') }}"></script>
</body>
```

I had extended this app.blade.php is all the views. Body CSS :

```
body {
    padding-top: 80px;
    font-family: 'Muli', sans-serif
}
```

for one of the react component (Error pages) I want my body  padding zero. So that when Error Page loads zero padding applied to body but for rest components padding does not overload . Here Error page have **relative_particle** class

```
 <body>
    <div id="app">
       <div data-reactroot="">
       <div>
         <!-- react-empty: 8 -->
       </div>
           **<div class="relative_particle">
           </div>**
       </div>
    </div>
</bod>
```

I want those components having **relative_particle** class div should have 0 padding body css . What can be done to solve it . 
**Note : I am not using jquery lib in my project .**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add this style for your error pages:

```
.nopadding {
   padding: 0 !important;
   margin: 0 !important;
}
```

Then you can do the following to add this class to the body:

```
document.body.className += ' ' + 'nopadding';
```

Make sure you run above script only on error pages. If you can't differentiate them, check if *relative_particle* class exists, then run above script.

You can see more details on manipulating body classes [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17457583/safe-and-quickest-way-to-add-a-css-class-to-the-body-of-the-dom).

Also make sure you [wait for the DOM](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9899372/pure-javascript-equivalent-of-jquerys-ready-how-to-call-a-function-when-t).